# recharts tickcount is not working for category

Tags: recharts

```
    <XAxis
    className="firstXaxis"
    domain={['dataMin', 'dataMax']}
    id="name"
    type="number"
    xAxisId="0"
    // domain={['auto', 'auto']}
    tickLine={false}
    axisLine={false}
    dataKey="date"
    stroke={'#414141 !important'}
    interval={0}
    tickCount={8}
/>
```

tried passing domain as auto and interval with different counts but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

the `tickCount` attribute of the `<XAxis />` child component is only used when `type="number"`. Did you forget to remove the line `type="number"` from your code? The default value for `type` being `"category"`.